# Scaling the contents of OpenGL ES framebuffer

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, rendering, framebuffer

Currently I'm scaling down the contents of my OpenGL ES 1.1 framebuffer like this:

1. save current framebuffer and renderbuffer references
2. bind framebuffer2 and smallerRenderbuffer
3. re-render all contents
4. now smallerRenderbuffer contains the "scaled-down" contents of
   framebuffer
5. do stuff with contents of smallerRenderbuffer
6. re-bind framebuffer and renderbuffer

**What's an alternative way to do this?** Perhaps I can just copy and scale the contents of the original framebuffer and renderbuffer into framebuffer2 and smallerRenderbuffer. Hence avoiding the re-render step. I've been looking at `glScalef` but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Note: this is all done in OpenGL ES 1.1 on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an initial render to texture, then render from that to both the frame buffer that you want to be visible and to the small version. Whatever way you look at it, what you're trying to do is use the data that has been rendered as the source for another rendering so rendering to a texture is the most natural thing to do.

You're probably already familiar with the semantics of a render to texture if you're doing work on the miniature version, but for completeness: you'd create a frame buffer object, use `glFramebufferTexture2DOES` to attach a named texture to a suitable attachment point, then bind either the frame buffer or the texture (ensuring the other isn't simultaneously bound if you want defined behaviour) as appropriate.

Comment: Cool thanks. In my case I don't want to modify the "main rendering" in the game. I can read over the code. However I don't want to modify it to render to a texture. So I'm stuck trying to use the contents of the main framebuffer and renderbuffer. I see two options: re-render into my own framebuffer and renderbuffer or somehow copy + scale the contents in the main framebuffer and renderbuffer.

Comment: So the main rendering is managing its own frame buffers and you've no way to nominate a target render buffer from outside?

Comment: That's correct. In this particular scenario my code is just a parasite... copying + scaling the contents of the buffers populated in the main rendering loop.